# Evidence for different learning applied to negative and positive feedback

Tags: cognitive-psychology, reference-request, reinforcement-learning

I was consulting a friend of mine while building a cognitive model for the Wisconsin Card Sorting Task and he mentioned that it's important to note that people respond differently to to positive feedback and negative.

What evidence is there that cognitively people take negative feedback into account differently than positive feedback in cognitive tasks? The only paper I've found so far is [this one on categorization](https://labs.psych.ucsb.edu/ashby/gregory/Ashby_OBrien_P%26P.pdf) and when I try searching for it, I only see business and organisation scale investigations.

Comment: A few more examples here: http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/9085/evidence-that-positive-rewards-are-learnt-faster-than-negative-rewards/9118#9118